# Swift iOS 11 Beta Today Widget infoPlist.Strings Not Localizing

Tags: ios, swift, localization, info-plist, ios10-today-widget

I have been using the Today Widget in my Swift program and have not had any issues, until I started using iOS 11 beta. Since then the `Bundle Display Name` is not getting localized. Within my `Info.Plist` I have:

```
<key>CFBundleDisplayName</key>
<string>NSLocalizedString(CFBundleDisplayName, nil)</string>
```

And in my `InfoPlist.Strings` files I have

```
"CFBundleDisplayName" = "Recent Chats";
```

If I display the widget on anything before iOS 11 beta, the String is localized properly, however when I use an iOS 11 beta device, the String `NSLocalizedString(CFBundleDisplayName, nil)` is displayed.

Does anyone know of a change in iOS 11 beta or bug that could be causing this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Did you test on ios 11 simulator or real device? If you test on simulator, Please change simulator language from Settings>General>Language&Region in simulator.

Another interesting thing which i realize that if you use base.lproj as only English version and there is no such a English localization, when simulator language is changed to Enlish(U.S) or English(U.K), InfoPlist.Strings (Base) value is not shown.

Comment: I actually tested on a simulator and actual device. Changing the language did help in finding the issue. I had to put the default string in the `Info.plist` and not the `NSLocalizedString` text.